# Access Google App Script Using Custom Domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I just tried using Google App Script and create a simple app for employee attendance with location permission. The application is work fine but now i want to use my own domain to access the app. is that possible? i've tried to add it to iframe and host it to Google Cloud Run but I can't get the location when tried to check-in.